# Mysql jdbc connector Database Metadata quoted identifier issue

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I was connecing to Mysql database via Mysql jdbc connector 5.1.15.

The table contains quoted identifiers( column name with special characters). I need to insert values into table.  I was trying to get the Metadata of the database and tried to get the `storesLowerCaseQuotedIdentifiers()`, `storesMixedCaseQuotedIdentifiers` and `storesUpperCaseQuotedIdentifiers`.

Among the three `storesMixedCaseQuotedIdentifiers` returns `false` where as `storesLowerCaseQuotedIdentifiers` and `.storesUpperCaseQuotedIdentifiers`  returns `true`. If Mysql supports both upper and lower case quoted identifiers then it can return `true` for `MixedCaseQuoted` identifier. Why it is returning true for both Loqwer and `UppercasequotedIdentifiers`?

Thanks in advance. Correct me if I am wrong.